# Specifying image sizes in shopify

Tags: image, shopify, sizing

Whilst trying to add image sizes to my website on Shopify it never seems they actually work when I look back on webpage speed tests. I've gone through multiple ways but it never appears to fix the problem.

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 custom_showcase custom_showcase1">
    <a href="{{ settings.custom_showcase1_link }}">
        {% if settings.custom_showcase1_img_toggle %}<img src="{{ 'custom_showcase1_img.jpg' | asset_url }}" style="width: 368px; height: 368px" />{% endif %}
        <div class="ins">
```

Any light on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You never size images with Shopify. When you add an image, Shopify takes care of all the sizes. You get nice Liquid filters to use when you want images of a certain size. You can even ask for your original image if needed. Hence the chore for designers is to ensure the merchant uploads nice artwork, well proportioned and ready for the auto resizing that happens.